# User's reputation behaves strangely

Tags: support, reputation

Clicking Andrey Vihrov name brings us to his User Profile but its reputation is no longer -143. Is it a bug?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The users page shows the reputation amount weekly, monthly, quarterly, yearly and totally. -143 is for the current week only, the user has 2959 at the moment.

Note, he has put 300 reputation for a bounty this week, which explains the loss. Besides that bounty investment he gained reputation.